# Why does setting an alias overwrite a executable link?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm curious, why does adding an entry to `.bashrc` cause a link to be overwritten? For example, on a testing machine, I installed Java with `apt-get install openjdk-7-jre` and then played round with `.bashrc` by adding `alias java="echo Java!"`. When I ran `java` from bash, I found that it echoed `Java!` instead of running java, located at `/usr/bin/java`. I have also found that this happens with `ps`, `sh` and `screen`. So why is this happening?

Comment: This is exactly what alias is supposed to do - replace the alias with the specified command when typed in the bash prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because that is how Bash works. It's in the manual - Aliases have a higher priority when trying to match input up with a command.

The common use of aliases is to override commands; for example:

```
alias java="\java -Xmx=1G"
```

The above alias raises the default maximum amount of memory available to a java process from 256MiB to 1GiB. The only way for this to have any useful effect, however, is if when I type `java`, it runs the alias and not the command.